# Parse Error: Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am getting a parse error on the below and I'm not sure why.  Thanks for any help!

```
   createObject :: [a] -> object a 
   createObject lst =
      let x = lst !! 0
      let y = lst !! 1
      let z = lst !! 2
      in object(x,y,z)

   test.hs:28:5: error: parse error on input `let'
   |
   28 |     let y = lst !! 1
```

Comment: You can replace the multiple `lets` by using eg. `createObject (x:y:z:_) = object (x,y,z)` (and you'll probably want to add a case for when the list is less than 3 elements long).

Answer (score 8):

`let-in` expressions in Haskell use only one `let`:

```
createObject :: [a] -> object a 
createObject lst =
  let x = lst !! 0
      y = lst !! 1
      z = lst !! 2
  in object(x,y,z)
```

In a `do` block, you do use multiple `let` bindings, but we don't use an `in` expression:

```
trivialExample :: [a] -> IO (Object a)
trivialExample lst = do 
  let x = lst !! 0 
  let y = lst !! 1 
  let z = lst !! 2
  return $ object (x,y,z)
```

Answer (score 1):

Each `let` must have its own `in` (except in `do` notation and list comprehensions).

You could therefore use

```
createObject lst =
      let x = lst !! 0
      in let y = lst !! 1
      in let z = lst !! 2
      in object(x,y,z)
```

but this is not idiomatic, since a single `let` can involve a block of definitions. Indeed, @jkeuhlen showed above the idiomatic use of `let`.

You should however avoid using `!!`, which is slow and partial, and prefer pattern matching whenever possible.

```
createObject :: [a] -> object a 
createObject [x,y,z] = object (x,y,z)
createObject _       = error "createObject: input list must have length 3"
```

or

```
createObject :: [a] -> object a 
createObject (x:y:z:_) = object (x,y,z)
createObject _         = error "createObject: input list must have length >= 3"
```

Note that the above is still a code smell: the input type `[a]` looks wrong, since it seems to allow any list length, when it actually works only on length 3 (or larger, in the second case, ignoring the other elements).

It is hard to guess what you actually need, here.